# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays

Very simple problem.but still unable to solve it.

I pass a message to array

`feet nimantha 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 120827`

Already i declared the array like this,

```
string[] arr1 = new string[10];
```

And after that, I tried it to

```
string[] arr1 = new string[11];
```

But both shows me this exception- `Index was outside the bounds of the array`

Code is here.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    string mobileNo = Request.QueryString["msisdn"];
    int  dest = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["shortcode"].ToString());
    string messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];
    string operatorNew = Request.QueryString["operator"];

    // Label1.Text = "ok";
    WriteToFile(mobileNo, dest, messageIn, operatorNew);
    if (messageIn != null) {
      string[] arr1 = new string[11];
      arr1 = messageIn.Split(' ');
      int size = arr1.Length;
      string arrmsg = "";
      foreach (string _element in arr1) {
        if (arrmsg == "")
          arrmsg = _element;
        else {
          arrmsg = arrmsg + "/" + _element;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch {}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I pass a message to array"? Please show your code - you haven't shown anything *accessing* an array yet, which makes it impossible to help you really...

Comment: You have only declared the array! Where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: `string[] arr = "feet nimantha 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 120827".Split(' ');` give you an array of 11 elements, how are you passing it to the array, post some code

Comment: Could you show code where your exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you show the code when the exception is fired>

Comment: Code Added.Please dont down vote.It's end of my life in stack overflow

Comment: The edit helps, but: which line throws this error? because none that I can see would actually cause an index-out-of-range: `foreach` knows about ranges. BTW, the `new string[11]` is redundant, because that array is **replaced** with the one from `messageIn.Split(' ')`. Is there some more code just under this that accesses something by index? perhaps in a string or the array? Also: is it possible that `WriteToFile` is throwing the exception?

Comment: What line in your code above is triggering the error you mention?

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad: Yeah, but where is the exception thrown? Wherever you're seeing it, it's probably providing a stack trace that should tell you the line number. Or you could even identify the line by stepping through the code with a debugger. (In fact, chances are if you do that it'll answer your question for you.)

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad to re-prompt: the error is not coming from the current code posted. So: either we need to see a bit more, or you need to look at the `.StackTrace` of the exception. Preferably both.

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad In one of the comments you stated that the message comes with "feet<space>nimantha<space>1<space>2<space>3<space>4<space>5<space>6<space>7<spac‌​e>8<space>9<space>120827"; there will be 12 elements when this string is splitted; but in the question the string you have provided is different. Please check the question again.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited as more code was added to the question):

Try replacing this:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[11]; 
arr1 = messageIn.Split(' ');
```

With the following:

```
string[] arr1 = messageIn.Split(new char[]{' '});
```

This may well result in an array longer than 11, but that does not matter - you don't need to specify length before you populate the array here.

Comment: The OP is already using string.Split. Making this change will not prevent the error. It removes an unnecessary and redundant array allocation, but nothing else (also, the OP's usage of `.Split` / `params` is more idiomatic)

Comment: @MarcGravell I think the error is occurring because an attempt is being made to populate an array specified to be of length 11, with more items than that. By avoiding the initial allocation, this should prevent the error. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: the array of length 11 is discarded; it is redundant. Sure, it isn't great to init and discard an array, but it **has no relation** on the error. From the next line, the only array that matters is the one that comes from `.Split()`

Comment: Ah, yes. Quite right. `arr1` in the OP is actually _replaced_, not just populated. I actually tested this to make sure. Apparently I was wrong... (Maybe this is different i Java?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing this with a character array.
In your case i would simply do:

```
arr1[0] = "feet nimantha 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 120827";
```

If that is not what you want see Kjartan.
Sry, what I wrote is wrong, the code came after I wrote this. :(

Comment: No.i wanted to add my message element by element.Message comes with feet<space>nimantha<space>1<space>2<space>3<space>4<space>5<space>6<space>7<space>8<space>9<space>120827

Answer (score 0):

If the result you need is

```
arrmsg = "feet/nimantha/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/120827"
```

and you have exception because your string array arr1 having unmatched length with result of string Split with whitespace
then you may declare and assign your string array to store the string Split result

```
//string[] arr1 = new string[11];
string[] arr1 = messageIn.Split(' ');
```

Then the arr1 can have different array size based on the string Split result. For example,

```
string messageIn ="feet nimantha 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 120827";
//arr1 is string[10] here
string[] arr1 = messageIn.Split(' ');

messageIn = "feet nimantha 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 120827 2132144";
//arr1 is string[11] here
arr1 = messageIn.Split(' ');
```

Therefore you don't need to worry about size of string array arr1 is not match the result of string Split.